# Does a Redundant Power Splitter Exist?

Tags: ups, electrical-power

We have two UPS units in our data center. All of our servers and network equipment have dual redundant supplies, one plugged into each UPS. We recently had a failure of one UPS. The servers and network hardware were not affected because they were still being powered by the other UPS. However, we have some equipment that only have a single source of power with no option for redundant power. They lost power during this failure. Are there any devices that could allow devices like this to plug into two power sources for redundancy?

Comment: I'd like to know this too.  Some expensive network equipment comes with only one power supply :-/

Comment: one word of advice that I'm sure you know already but I'd rather you know twice than not at all is that you need to ensure that both of your UPSs in the scenario you describe above are connected to the same electrical phase. Failing to do this will put your equipment and safety at risk.

Comment: @Chopper3, there is equipment available for doing this safely, despite the sources being fed from different electrical phases.  The APC Transfer Switches will do exactly this by detecting when one source fails and quickly switching to another source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something list [this](http://www.apc.com/products/family/index.cfm?id=14&tab=features) APC Rack-mount Transfer Switch, maybe?

Answer (score 3):

Yes - a transfer switch - something like [this](http://www.wti.com/p-167-pts-9cm20-2-automatic-power-transfer-switch.aspx) or [this](http://www.apc.com/products/family/index.cfm?id=14&tab=features)

Answer (score 2):

Some equipment I've dealt with before, you could remove the standard AC power supply, drop in a DC supply, then use a special splitter cable to attach that to more than one external AC to DC power supplies.

Comment: A description of "some equipment" would be nice; this is too vague otherwise.

Comment: In this case it was all Cisco equipment.